# how to transmit png or jpg in a http proxy

Tags: http, sockets, png, jpeg

I am working on a http proxy in linux using c sockets. The io function i used is *robust io* 
introduced in *Computer Systems:A Programmer's Perspective*.

Now everything works fine, except when I transmit jpg or png part embedded in a web page. It is always a red cross where a picture should appear. Can someone help me or have any suggestions?
sorry for the details.I mean i am working on a http proxy.The logic is the client initiate a web page request from IE browser,the the proxy will start a DNS query and send the same request to server and send the reply to client. the receive and send reply information is very simple,
`while((number = readnb(&rio,buf,n))>=0){ 
writen(fd,buf,number);
}` 
the result is if there is jpg or png in a web page,then the browser shows nothing, i typed CTRL+C to stop the proxy, the browser will show the character parts and red cross for the jpg part

Comment: You need to supply more information. Download the PNG or jpg [sic] (you mean JPEG) using a web browser or a command line HTTP client like `curl`, and compare the result with the file that lives on the server. You may notice a clue.

Comment: exactly, check the direct link to the image.

Answer (score 0):

> the result is if there is jpg or png in a web page,then the browser
>   shows nothing

It sounds like you don't support [persistent HTTP connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection).

Check whether you can individually access the images.

Comment: I have tried to set connection to keep-alive which doesn't help.I tried to visit www.yahoo.com, it turns out the same thing. It shows nothing except when i stoped the proxy.the words part is ok while the pictures part is red cross. but if i visit simple sites like www.google.com, the doodles shows OK.Any suggestion.

Comment: 1) no that's client side, you need support in your server 2) does it work for a direct image link?

Comment: I have checked the pictures in the web pages,they direct to url of another pages not the url of the pictures themselves. Should i use wireshark to find the request for these images?